# my python code can't read new notifications

Tags: python, facebook

I'm working on a python code which receives new notifications on facebook and sends "m" to serial port
(which is arduino connected to PC)

On the python monitor you can write your email and password to log in to your facebook
and if there's no new notification yet, 'Zzz...' appears. If there is new notification, 'New Notification on Facebook, hoisting flag ...' appears on the monitor.

For logging in facebook and printing 'Zzz...' it works pretty fine. But the thing is, even if there's new notification on my facebook, the code doesn't show any difference on the screen.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import serial
import sys
import time
import warnings
'VERSION 2.3 Unlike version 2.0, in this implementation: Instead of counting starting from 2 HTML tags <div class="c"> default, and'
'possible clikkare the link: clik on Clear Notifications (will not be '
'just a <div class="c">) and start counting for> 1'
'In this way, we avoid counting invitations to events or warnings as if they were birthday notifications.'
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 
# hiding any warning 
SERIALPORT = raw_input("Enter the serial port to which' the connected device:") 

# Set up serial port 
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(SERIALPORT, 9600)
    ser.timeout = None
except serial.SerialException:
    print "No device connected. exiting..."
    time.sleep(4)
    sys.exit()

# Alternatively you can 'go on facebook. com / notifications.php and lean to feed (using then the python library: feedparser). 
# Browser 
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar 
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj) 

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
#br.set_handle_grip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False) 

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh> 0 
# br.set_handle_refresh (mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor (), max_time = 1) 



# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?) 
br.addheaders = [('User-agent' , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)')] 

# Open some site, let's pick a random one, the first That pops into mind: 
r = br.open('http://m.facebook.com') 
#html= r.read() 

# Show the source 
#print html
# or  
#print br. response (). read () 

# Show the html title 
print "- Connected to:" + br.title ()

# Select the first (index zero) form 
br.select_form(nr = 0) 

try: 
    wait = input("\ n Every how many seconds you want to check for new notifications? ") 
    while(wait>=5):
        wait = input(" \ n - E 'recommended a value below 5 seconds. \ n Re-Enter a value: ") 
except: 
    print "It 's necessary to enter a numeric value, not a string. \ n Closing the program ..."
    time.sleep(5) 
    sys.exit() 

print "\ n - Enter your login for Facebook: \ n "
# Let's search 
br.form['email'] = '% s'% raw_input(" Enter Email ") 
br.form['pass'] = '% s'% raw_input(" Enter Password: ") 

br.submit()
x = br.response().read() 
z = x.count("Combination e-mail/password incorrect.") 

while z: 
    print "Unable to login, username or password incorrect. Retry: \ n "
    go = False
    br. select_form (nr = 0) 
    br. form ['email'] = '% s'% raw_input (" Enter Email ") 
    br. form ['pass'] = '% s'% raw_input ("Enter Password:") 
    br. submit () 
    x = br. response().read () 
    z = x. count("Combination e-mail/password incorrect.")
else: 
    # we are fully logged.  (Z = 0)
    go = True 
    status = False #status flag, lowered = False 
    try:
        br.Follow_link(text = 'Delete notifications', nr = 0) # Clear previous notifications 
    except: 
        print "\ n No Notification! \ n "
    print " \ n - Mark as read, all previous notifications ... \ n "
    ser.write(" n ") # report the servant to the starting position. 

while True and go: 
    try: 
      # br.reload ( ) 
      # print br.response (). read () 
      x = br.open ('http://m.facebook.com/home.php?refid=0').read () 
      i = x.count ('< div class = "c"> ') # This field HTML is repeated more' than one time if there 'a new notification (before but' are read all notifications such events etc..). 
    except: 
        print "Delay in charge the page, wait 3 seconds applied .. \ n "
        time.sleep(3) 
    if i>= 1: 
        notification = True # Notifications to read 
    else:
        i = 0 #No notification 
        notification = False 

# to read control: 
    if notification == True: 
        if status == False: # If the flag and the 'down 
            ser.write("m") 
            print "New Notification on Facebook, hoisting flag ..." 
            status = True 
        else: 
            print "There are still notifications view ... "

    elif status == False: 
        print " Zzz ... " #flag already 'down, no notification to view 

    else: 
        ser.write("n") 
        print "No new notification flag down ... "
        status = False 

    time.sleep(wait) # Wait before checking for new notifications 

#END
```

I think there's some kind of problem with receiving data from facebook, which from the code :

```
while True and go: 
    try: 
      # br.reload ( ) 
      # print br.response (). read () 
      x = br.open ('http://m.facebook.com/home.php?refid=0').read () 
      i = x.count ('< div class = "c"> ') # This field HTML is repeated more' than one time if there 'a new notification (before but' are read all notifications such events etc..). 
    except: 
        print "Delay in charge the page, wait 3 seconds applied .. \ n "
        time.sleep(3) 
    if i>= 1: 
        notification = True # Notifications to read 
    else:
        i = 0 #No notification 
        notification = False
```

What do you think? The coding was done from python 2.7.

Comment: Why don't you just use the notifications API?

Comment: How do I use it? Never heard of that.